# Intellij remote debugging: change connection timeout

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I'm trying to debug a machine that is located in China (very far from here) and the connection is very slow. The timeout of intellij remote debugger is short and therefore I'm getting Unable to open debugger port : java.net.ConnectException "Connection timed out: "

And I can't debug. Is it possible to increase the connection timeout? and how?

Comment: Does `telnet` connect? You need to verify that connection is not blocked as it may have nothing to do with timeout.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - yes I verified it

Comment: What OS do you use? Does it help if you disable firewall?

Answer (score 2):

Try add `-Djava.net.connectiontimeout=<seconds>` to `<IDEA_install_path>/bin/idea.vmoptions` and restart IDEA.
But firstly ensure that port is opened and host is accessible, for example you can try to connect with `telnet`/another program.

Comment: I have the same problem. Should I restart IntelliJ IDEA to make it work?

Comment: edit idea64.exe.vmoptions for the X64 version